# Sessions and shared hosting (Asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, session, hosting

I'm currently having some trouble with my shared hosting as I can't use sessions because they time-out after about 20 seconds (when the appPool gets recycled I guess)I've looked into using the sqlServer or sessionState mode but the hosting company doesn't have these set up or I can't install them and seems to think that cookies are a viable alternative.

Can anyone recommend any hosting company that offers a shared solution where sessions work and is preferably in the uk.

After looking around today I think im going to go for a vps solution as I don't think it is available anywhere on a shared hosting plan.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session in ASP.NET should just work.  The AppPool default recycle is around 26 hours or so.  If the AppPool is recycling after 20 seconds I'd put in a support request for your hosting provider.  Otherwise, the SqlServer session allows you to have any named database as your aspnet session store (you can configure this in your web.config file under `<sessionState>`.

So, this means that any ASP.NET hosting provider that allows you a sql server database can give you session state.  There are a lot of these in the UK. One is fasthosts.